# On Chrome, what is the difference between ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED?

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I am debugging a problem in which the user is seeing `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` and, sometimes, `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` on Google Chrome.

I am surprised but apparently Google does not have a comprehensive list of possible network errors with explanations and possible causes.

From what I understand, please correct me if I am wrong, `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` means that the connection could be stablished, however, the server did not send any data. When I say it did not send any data, I mean, it did not even send response headers. This is different from a correct response with `Content-Length: 0`

This is an example of a CURL request with empty response:

```
chad-integration:~ # curl -v 111.222.159.30
* About to connect() to 111.222.159.30 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 111.222.159.30... connected
* Connected to 111.222.159.30 (111.222.159.30) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.0     OpenSSL/0.9.8h zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.10
> Host: 111.222.159.30
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 111.222.159.30 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

However, what is the difference from an empty response and a connection closed? Does this mean that, for `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` the backend sent **some data** but then closed the connection?

Comment: Is it possible you're using plain HTTP on a server that does HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the chromium site which is the brains of Chrome, Edge etc.

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/base/net_error_list.h?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2Fchromium%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2Fbase%2Fnet_error_list.h

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.